# Google Client Authorize doesn't work on Mobile IOS IPhone(41.0.2272.58)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, google-chrome

We use gapi.js for Google authorising.
It works correct on majority of desktop browsers and on mobile Safari.
But it doesn't on  Mobile Chrome IOS(41.0.2272.58).

In the begging we load gapi.js script

```
require(['https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=gapiIsLoaded'];
```

Then we try authorize using:

```
gapi.auth.authorize(params, handler);
```

Params are

```
var params = {
                client_id: MY_CLIENT_ID,
                scope: MY_SCOPES,
                immediate: false // to open popup
            };
```

Browsers shows popup and I can autorize and continue work.
IOS Safari works correct too.

But Chrome IOS never calls `handler` callback.

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/189

Comment: why did you post an issue at github and here? what is your question?

Comment: i'm not sure that they follow their github questions but they always follow github

Comment: this isn't a question.

Comment: It's a serious bug and I want to discuss it maybe someone has a workaround

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/189 updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolve by adding redirect ur instead of window open https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/189

Answer (score 1):

This issue extends to Chrome for Android 5.0. In my case, downgrading to 39.0.2171.59 resolves the problem. Hopefully this information puts you closer to finding the root cause.